# OkHttpClient.newCall bug?

Tags: android, okhttp

I have one client who has android 4 and he have to download some images from your server, in other versions of android (> 4) it works fine, version 5 for example.

Code:

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .connectTimeout(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
            .writeTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .build();
request = new Request.Builder().url(urlProd).build();
response = client.newCall(request).execute(); // In this line its returns nothing and no have error messages
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OkHttp 3.13+ requires Android 5+.
https://cashapp.github.io/2019-02-05/okhttp-3-13-requires-android-5

Comment: You can use OkHttp 3.12.13 for older client support.